# On finding an inequality utilizing the norm of projections.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, inequality

I was looking at [this](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~johnson/14_08_04PositiveBasisL.pdf) paper where a Schauder basis for $L_1(0, \infty)$ is found and I could not understand how an inequality was derived.

To facilitate the curious reader I will upload the definition of Haar functions and the full proposition where I do not understand how the inequality was derived. Still I advise answerers to skip down to **my problems** that involve only the last inequality.

[image]

[image]

Here are **my problems**:

- How do I find the conditional expectation projection onto the closed span of $\{ 1_{(i-1,i)}  \}^{\infty}_{i = 1}$ and how do I obtain its norm?
- What is the complementary projection on $\{ h_i\}^{\infty}_{i =1}$ and how do I find its norm?